# If I use SQLite auto increment on a column, does it automatically maintain an index on that column?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, rdbms

I am using auto increment on an integer data column in SQLite. Since it is auto increment, the data is already sorted by that column in ascending order. So, I was wondering if SQLite will perform a binary search over the auto increment column whenever a data is searched by that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively yes, but not really.

That is, all **AUTOINCREMENT** does is add a constraint that requires the value assigned to the column to be higher than any existing value, or higher than any value that has been used, in that column.

But there's more to it than that it is `your_column INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` *(AUTOINCREMENT can only be used on such a column and there can only be 1 such column per table)* makes that column an alias of the hidden **rowid** column.

The **rowid** is what is indexed, and is basically the most primary index and the most efficient, which always exists unless the table is defined using the WITHOUT ROWID keyword.

So an **AUTOINCREMENT** column is an alias of the **rowid** column and uses a differnt, **more expensive** algorithm than an alias of the **rowid** without AUTOINCREMENT.

That is without **AUTOINCREMENT** the value generated for the **rowid** column will find the maximum value in the table and increment it. Unless that value exceeds 9223372036854775807 in which case SQlite will make some attempts to find an unused lower value (normally between 1 and 9223372036854775807).

With **AUTOINCREMENT** the algorithm takes the higher value of the maximum value and a value stored in the table **sqlite_sequence** for the respective table and uses that (thus any deleted higher valueswill not be re-used). However if 9223372036854775807 has been used then an **SQLITE_FULL** error will be raised.

The following should be noted :-

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.

[SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) you may well want to read this.

### Additional

regrading the comment :-

> If I don't use AUTOINCREMENT I have to explicitly create unique
>   integer IDs and then insert them in database each time a new row is
>   inserted.

The following demonstrates that there is no requirement for AUTOINCREMENT:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS xyz (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES(null);
SELECT * FROM xyz;
```

After running twice the result is :-

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the fact that using AUTOINCREMENT comes with an extra cost. But, I'm working on a database such that it does not have any valid column(s) which can be used as primary key. That's why I'm explicitly creating unique IDs to identify each row by using "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT". Any thoughts on this problem?

Comment: I can see any need for using AUTOINCREMENT `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` would do the same more efficiently unless you reached 9223372036854775807 rows. In which case with AUTOINCREMENT you can no longer insert into the table, whilst without you may be able to if rows have been deleted (although there is a get around to allow negative numbers so basically doubling the rows). I don't really understand what your problem is.

Comment: If I don't use AUTOINCREMENT I have to explicitly create unique integer IDs and then insert them in database each time a new row is inserted. AUTOINCREMENT does that work for me, it automatically gives me an integer which is unique each time I insert a new row. And since my table is pretty small, I think it will never reach the value 9223372036854775807. That's why I'm using AUTOINCREMENT.

Comment: No you don't. e.g. `CREATE TABLE xyz (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES(null);`

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out, it makes a lot more sense now. Previously I thought that I have to explicitly specify ID while inserting new row if I don't use AUTOINCREMENT. But, now I know that it will automatically give me unique ID even if I don't use AUTOINCREMENT. Thanks again !

Comment: @user3752033 the prime reason for INTEGER PRIMARY KEY aliasing rowid is to allow the assignment of unique id's. However, beware, I think this is pretty much unique to SQLite.